# PHP - Adjust Hour pulled from RSS feed for Daylight Savings

Tags: php, rss, dst

I've got a PHP script which pulls from an RSS feed and produces a series of outputs based on events. The script was working fine until last week, when daylight savings changed.

The script is working off an RSS feed which has the date in the following structure:

pubDate: Thu, 04 Apr 2013 19:05:00 GMT

I needed to create different php scripts for each day and time, so I used the following:

```
$expiry = $item->pubDate;
$expiryLenght = strlen("$expiry");
$timeStart = $expiryLenght - 12;
$time = substr("$expiry","$timeStart", 5);
$hour = substr("$time",0, 2);
$day_alpha = substr("$expiry",0, 3);
$day = substr("$expiry",5, 2);
$month = substr("$expiry",8, 3);
$year = substr("$expiry", 12, 4);
$month = strtolower($month);
$month_num = monthNum($month);
```

The important part for me is the '$hour' line. I need to try and adjust that for daylight savings. The pubDate is always in GMT un-adjusted.

I was thinking of going down the route of defining the daylight savings period, and if it is within the timeframe, add 1 to the hour. However, I'm not sure that that is a good solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Dave.

---

After much help from the comments, I ended up using this

```
$expiry1 = $item->pubDate;
```

$expiry = date('D, d M Y H:i:s \off', strtotime($expiry1 . " Europe/Dublin"));

Bit of a hackjob,  but it put the Expiry  back into the format it was previously in, which meant the rest of the code could work off it.

Comment: You should build a date object from these values and work with that.

Comment: @deed02392 Agreed. Look at this post for inspiration http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2012/08/why-php-datetime-rocks

Comment: The hour alone is not enough to go on. You'd be out by a day in the first hour of each new day, and by a month on the first of each month of summer time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$expiry = "Thu, 04 Apr 2013 19:05:00 GMT";
echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A', strtotime($expiry . " America/New_York"));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm at work right now so can't test this but I believe you want to do something along these lines:

```
<?php
$timestring = 'Thu, 04 Apr 2013 19:05:00 GMT';
$mytimezone = new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Nauru');
$datetime = date_create_from_format('D, d M Y h:i:s T', $timestring, $mytimezone);

echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP');
```

This creates a DateTime object from the string formatted as you specified, but with the Timezone you choose. So you choose the Timezone, it parses the date/time from your RSS feed and converts it to the timezone of your choosing.

It's also a lot less code than what you're currently doing. :-)

Comment: Thanks very much for this. My PHP skills aren't great so I wasn't able to get the rest of the script working after this even though this worked great. Really appreciate it!

Comment: To get it to work with the rest of your script, you probably just need to replace references to stuff like `$hour` to `$datetime->format('H')` using the appropriate of this fancy list of options: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php